# LDO: Is it OK if the input voltage is lower than the output voltage?

Tags: ldo, usb-pd

I'd like to adopt the [TPS7A20-5V](https://www.mouser.tw/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/TPS7A2050PDBVR?qs=hd1VzrDQEGgpoyZ%2F5FZYnQ%3D%3D) as LDO for USB input and output in my analog circuit:
[Datasheet [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a20.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1672622309860&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fau.mouser.com%252F) ]

```
| USB+C-5V in | ---> | TSP7A20-5V| ---> | Analog circuit |
```

AFAIK, general USB adapter (charger) output voltage is about 5.0 to 5.1 V, and an LDO's Vout should be lower than Vin.

The TSP7A20-5V has a 145 mV drop at max. 300 mA output.

If I have a heavy load because the TSP7A20-5V must output 300 mA, in this heavy load case,
does Vo still output a stable (5 V - drop) voltage (keep good performance of PSRR and low noise)?

Or is adopting a 4.5 V LDO TSP7A20-4.5V better than using the TSP7A20-5V in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short - same as final conclusion

- A 4.5V LDO would be safer.
  A 5V LDO may well work most of the time.
  If "may well work most of the time" is acceptable then 5V may do.
  If 4.5V out is acceptable then I'd choose a 4.5V LDO.

---

The results for Vin < Vout_reg are device dependent and without specific knowledge of the IC it is not possible to be sure.

I have seen regulators which drop out or regulation gracefully, and others which misbehave.

This is only informed guesstimate but, in this case, the 145 mV dropout sounds  as if the output is a P Channel device with the whole supply voltage available to provide Vgson , and the voltage drop being mainly due to pass transistor Rdson plus a very small extra due to other resistance.
145 mV at 300 mA =~ 480 milliohm equivalent.
The data sheet is extensive. TI know their stuff.
I'd expect a graceful dropout with no sudden surprises. I may be surprised.

Figure 6.33 indicated that the 145 mV Vdropout is worst case (Vout = 1.5V) at 50 degrees C, and that typical values at Vout = 5V are 100 mV at 0 degrees C and under 110 mV at 50 degrees C junction temperature.

Fig 6.4 gives an excellent overview of thermal resistance for the various packages via various paths.
At worst case 200 C/W junction to ambient, 300 mA and say 150 mV drop (45 mW dissipation) junction rise above ambient is 9 degrees C - so at say 40 C ambient you get typical Vdropout of about 106 mV.

SO:

At 5V in it will *probably* work.
USB actual voltages vary and depending on whether you at a port or two unpowered USB hubs in series (Look to my left. Cough) voltage may be slightly lower.

A 4.5V LDO would be safer.
A 5V LDO may well work most of the time.
If "may well work most of the time" is acceptable then 5V may do.
If 4.5V out is acceptable then I'd choose a 4.5V LDO.

[image]

Comment: Good answer, many thanks! I'm concluding: Whether Vin<Vo (a little) of LDO can work normally, it depend on how LDO design. <-  In general that's fine.  It also dependent on Vusb_bus input, If Vusb_bus always >= 5.0V seems to be fine.